How much does the sound an organism produces scale with size?
Specifically, I'm referring to decibels here, sound energy produced, not frequency.
If a human were scaled up or down, how would the sound energy produced by their voice scale with their size? Instinctually I want to say a cubed rate based on their lung volume, given that I've heard human voice volume is dependent largely on the amount of air being blown across the vocal cords, but of course, the vocal cords are also a factor here, and I don't know how to fit those in. How does this all fit together? A squared rate with scale? A cubed rate with scale? Would it not change considerably? Or something else entirely?
Just to reiterate, I'm specifically looking for sound energy produced here, a figure that can be used to calculate decibels. I've seen similar questions asked here before but they all get answered with frequency.
And of course, assume just enough handwaving with the scaling up/scaling down so the organism doesn't collapse under its own weight.

How much, or how? It's not just sound pressure level that changes. Lots of qualities change as well. On average.

"I'm referring to decibels here, sound energy produced, not frequency." There's a contradiction here, since decibels (the way the term is commonly used in the context of sound) measure amplitude, not energy or power. To find the power (sound energy per unit time) of an acoustic source, you need to know the amplitude AND the frequency.

@BrendanMitchell Yep! Other answers have explained that, thank you though.

It is quite easy to produce high-pitched loud sounds, but it is very much more difficult to produce low-pitched loud sounds. Basically, to produce loud low-pitched sounds there is no replacement for size. A referee's whistle is tiny but it is very loud; you can hear it all across a sportsball stadium; but to fill a stadium with deep low sound you need ginormous loudspeakers.
The difficulty comes from the need to couple the mechanical energy of the vibrating thingy with the free air. The lower the frequency of the sound, the bigger the device (called an acoustic horn) required for acoustic impedance matching.
All in all, a scaled down human can be as loud as a normal sized human if you want them to be; but when speaking or singing loudly their voice will be high pitched exactly because they are small. On the other hand, a scaled up human will easily be able to speak or sing louder than a normal sized human, and their voice will be deeper because they are large.
Note that if the scaling factor is reasonably close to one, say between 0.8 and 1.25, individual variation may be as large as the expected effect of the scaling, just how in the real world of unscaled humans there are women singers capable of singing in the baritone register and men singers capable of singing in the mezzosoprano register.
Note: About those vocal folds (or "chords", but they are not chords). The size and thickness of the vocal chords themselves is what gives the sound its lowest pitch; but the volume is controlled primarily by the amount of air and the size of the vocal tract.
One way humans and most mammals make vocal sounds is to put some tension in the vocal folds and blow air through the opening; the vocal folds vibrate like the strings of a guitar or piano. The higher the tension on the vocal folds, the higher the pitch of the sound. But just like on an acoustic guitar or a piano, the volume of the sound produced directly by the vibrating string is tiny, and needs to be amplified by the resonance box of the instrument.
Fun experiment: Pluck the strings of an electric guitar, which is designed without a resonance box because the sound is intended to be amplified electronically, and notice how quiet the sound is compared with an acoustic guitar.

Wait people are saying "chords" for vocal chords? I always thought it was "cords", like wires.

@Parrotmaster: The traditional form is c>h<ords. Cords without an aitch is a newer form, like archeology instead of archaeology. (Traditionally English keeps the spelling of Latin words when it Englishes them, and in Latin is chorda from Greek chordē, a string of a musical instrument.) As far as I know both spellings are acceptable, except in geometry and in music where only the form with see aitch is considered correct.

I am afraid it's not as simple as that.
For a reference, dogs are smaller than us, I would say roughly by a factor between 1/2 and 1/4, but still a barking dog can produce a sound of 80 - 100 dB, while a shouting human stands at 80 - 90 dB (source).
Cicadas, which are even smaller, register up to 106 dB (Source).
And if you have ever heard a newborn screaming and crying, I am pretty sure you agree their sound level is not scaled down at all with their size.

Dogs are shaped differently from us, and cicadas use a tymbal.
A baby's vocal cords are not proportionate to their size, they're roughly 1/2 width on average- plus babies are always screaming at the top of their lungs, while older humans aren't. A baby human screaming is 80-115 db, while an adult human screaming is up to 85-125 (and db is logarithmic so that's a difference of x10, which directly contradicts what you said.)
All examples given here are ignoring what I asked, which is about a directly scaled down human.
I realize this won't be simple but I'd appreciate a serious answer.

A dog's voicebox is a significantly cruder tool than that of a human. Fine-grained control tends to come at the cost of raw power output. For the posted question, dogs and humans are apples and oranges.

I upvoted @L.Dutch's answer, but I want to build on it.
In most cases, increasing size decreases frequency and since lower frequencies need more energy to move air (because more volume is involved) the decibels are, in fact, basically the same.
We're dealing with a human. That means we're scaling not just the voice box and mouth (which control the frequency) but also the lungs (which control the volume of air).
As the human is scaled up, the volume of air in the lungs increases, but so does the voice box and mouth, decreasing the average frequency of the voice. Very simplistically the increased air balances out the decreased average frequency and the number of decibels is the same.
Scale the human down and you get less air but a higher average frequency... same number of decibels.
In reality, as @L.Dutch states, it's NOT this simple. I've met small women with deep voices and large men with high voices despite that being contrary to the average. Lung capacity, vocal control, voice box and shape of the mouth, etc. come in an amazing number of variations — but my unscientific rule-of-thumb tells me that all adults tend to shout at about the same number of decibels.
That's my story and I'm sticking to it.

Decibels sound pressure $\text{dB}\text{SPL}$ and decibels sound level, usually $\text{dB}\text{A}$, are different things, because humans can only hear sounds within a certain range of frequencies and the relationship between sound pressure and loudness is highly dependent on frequency. See A-weighting. It is the acoustic analog of the difference between radiant power measured in watts and luminosity measured in lumens.

@AlexP You're not wrong, but it's a level of detail that's beyond the needs of the OP. The simplification I employed still works for the purpose.

@AlexP that is a very interesting subject! It might be beyond the scope of the question but I still appreciate you sharing that, it did actually explain something I had trouble fully understanding, so it's very helpful.

I think you might want to research a physiological relationship called "allometry", where features (in this case sound production) vary with body size.
In many cases, the relationship is not linear, but scales to a power of the body mass: F = c x M^P,
where F = feature, c = a constant, M= body mass and P is the exponent of the power. For mammals, metabolic rate is around 0.75.
Wikipedia has the usual brief scan of information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allometry
But there are numerous other scientific papers that might help you, here are four:
https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/allometry-the-study-of-biological-scaling-13228439/ (general)
https://peerj.com/articles/16322/ (frogs)
https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsbl.2020.0081 (mammals)
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-11000-x (primates - maybe most relevant to your situation, but it deals with frequencies more than volumes.
Some birds can produce some very loud noises via their syrinx (which although not a human larynx, does a similar job), while others of similar size don't make much noise at all. Emus make relatively low noises and are quite big, (tying in with AlexP 's answer), pelicans are big but aren't loud, while kookaburras are medium sized and produce a lot of noise. (Guess where I live?).
